# Import ACF Repeater Field Values from CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to import a load of data into a sub fields of a repeater field (mortgage_providers) using file field (dd_csv) to upload the file to a post and return an array. Then loop through each row with PHP and update the repeater fields. I have tried the following but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
      if( get_field('dd_csv') ) {
        // load csv with SERVER PATH instead of URL
        $csv = get_attached_file(get_field('dd_csv')['id']);
        if(($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
          $count = 0;
          while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // $count = acf row, $data[0] = csv column 1 value
            update_sub_field(array('mortgage_providers', $count, 'mortgage_provider_name'), $data[0], 'option');
            $count++;
          }

          fclose($handle);
        }
      }
```

Here's a sample of the data:

- at symbol Sipp
- 012 Property Shares
- 121 Legals
- 1st Source Direct
- 1st Stop Finance
- 33 KWS
- 3i
- 3M
- 3mc
- 3XD
- 5 Arrows
- AA Commercial Insurance
- AIG
- A1 Lender not relevant
- AA Friendly Society
- AA Insurance
- Abacus
- ...

In total there's over 1000 rows in column 1 of the CSV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hook into the [on save action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/):

```php
<?php

add_action( 'save_post', 'prefix_check_files', 10, 3 );

function prefix_check_files( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
if( get_field('dd_csv', $post_id) ) {
  // load csv with SERVER PATH instead of URL
  $csv = get_attached_file(get_field('dd_csv', $post_id)['id']);
  if(($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $count = 0;
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      // $count = acf row, $data[0] = csv column 1 value
      update_sub_field(array('mortgage_providers', $count, 'mortgage_provider_name'), $data[0], 'option');
      $count++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
}
}
```